# When searching an Access database from an Excel userform is it possible to search other columns than just the ID column?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, search, userform

I would like to search the access database with the user initials in the UserInitials column but I get the error *no value given for one or more required parameters*

However, if I search the database with the ID in the ID column it works perfectly fine.

Is it possible to do this? I have checked the spelling which is fine and there are no empty fields in the database itself. I have also changed and set the Primary key from ID to UserInitials but this doesn't seem to make any difference.
Many thanks.

```
Public Function searchDatabase()

If UserForm1.TextBox4.Value = "" Then
MsgBox "field empty"

Else

Dim con As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset


con.connectionstring = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data 
Source=C:\Users\MyPC\Desktop\DatabaseOne.accdb;"
'Open Db connection
con.Open
Set rs.ActiveConnection = con
rs.Open "Select * from TableUser where UserInitials= " & UserForm1.TextBox4.Text & ""

StartRow = 3
Do Until rs.EOF

'User Initials
UserForm1.TextBox1.Text = rs.Fields(1).Value
'User Full Name
UserForm1.TextBox2.Text = rs.Fields(2).Value
'User Email
UserForm1.TextBox3.Text = rs.Fields(3).Value

rs.MoveNext
StartRow = StartRow + 1
Loop
Set rs = Nothing
con.Close
Set con = Nothing

End If

End Function
```

Comment: @Storax  That works, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to embed `UserForm1.TextBox4.Text` in quotation marks otherwise the SQL statement will not be interpreted correctly

Try

```
 rs.open "Select * from TableUser where UserInitials= '" & UserForm1.TextBox4.Text & "'"
```

Further reading [Quotation marks in string expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/concepts/criteria-expressions/include-quotation-marks-in-string-expressions)